# Order a list of objects by it's DateTime property

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datetime, lambda

Imagine following class:

```
Class Person {
  DateTime birthdate;
}
```

I do have a list with some Person-objects:

```
List<Person> persons;
```

This list has already been through some special sorts, which about you don't have to care.
Just keep in mind, that the current order should be preserved.

**Now the list should be ascending sorted by the birthdate**.
**Also the birthdate could be NULL!**

I did use following, but I ended up getting it sorted alphanumeric, instead of from the newest date to the oldest date:

```
persons = persons.Where(p => p.birthdate != null).OrderBy(p => p.birthdate).ToList();
```

I'm aware of the fact, that persons, which have got NULL as birthdate, will be dropped out.
This is okay.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: " birthdate could be NULL!" but it's not a nullable `DateTime`.

Comment: And no, the code you've given will *not* sort alphanumerically. It will sort oldest to newest, but that can be fixed using `OrderByDescending`. Currently it won't compile though, as you'd need a `ToList()` call. Please produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem... there's too much wrong at the moment for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I corrected your mentioned errors.
As you tell me my code snippet will sort as i expected, my error must be somewhere else in the code. That already helped me enough! Thank you very much :)

Comment: If you have an ordering A1990-A1978-A1864-A2014-B1993-B1123-B2012-B1534, should A and B be sorted individually (so A and B stay together, but are each sorted) or should they be mixed? Because the final sort always takes precedence. If you want A and B to remain separate, you need to first sort on date and then on the AB part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use a `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` if you want to support `null`. I suspect that your real code is not what you've shown us because that won't order "alphanumerically" as mentioned.

However, this should work if you use a `Nullable<DateTime>` (also take note of  `ToList`):

```
persons = persons
    .Where(p => p.birthdate.HasValue)
    .OrderBy(p => p.birthdate.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Second, *"This list has already been through some special sorts, which about you don't have to care. Just keep in mind, that the current order should be preserved."*

How should we show you the way to keep the current order if we don't know how it *was* ordered?

Comment: Like I said in the other comment, that I know now, the code should work, helps me a lot. Thank you for the tip with the nullable property. :)